# How to draw an arrowhead line with svg in react native

Tags: reactjs, svg, native

Original question:

Like in this picture but with a full triangle. And i need to be able to set the line x1,y1,x2,y2. Thanks!

[this image (can't post it because I ain't got enogh reputation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhPLs.png)

EDIT:

Im using "react-native-svg" here's what I have: a plain line :(

```
<Svg
 height="1000"
 width="1000"
 >
  <Line
  x1={this.state.circle1.x}
  y1={this.state.circle1.y}
  x2={this.state.circle2.x}
  y2={this.state.circle2.y}
  stroke="#1abc9c"
  strokeWidth="10"
 />
</Svg>
```

Comment: React native doesn't natively support svg. You need to use a package like `react-native-svg`. What have you tried? can you post code on your attempts?

Comment: Hey! @JohnRuddell thanks for your reply, I updated my question

Comment: Those arrowheads can be done with [svg markers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker)

Answer (score 0):

OK so I figure it out. This is probably a really bad implementation but it works. If someone can improve this answer please do:

```
<Svg
    height="1000"
    width="1000"
>
    <G
        rotation={(Math.atan2(this.state.point2.y - this.state.point1.y, this.state.point2.x - this.state.point1.x) * 180 / Math.PI)+45}
        origin={`${this.state.point1.x}, ${this.state.point1.y}`}
    >
        <Path d={`M ${this.state.point1.x+8} ${this.state.point1.y+8} L ${this.state.point1.x-10} ${this.state.point1.y+10} L ${this.state.point1.x-8} ${this.state.point1.y-8} z`} fill="#1abc9c" stroke="#1abc9c" />
    </G>
        <G
            rotation={(Math.atan2(this.state.point2.y - this.state.point1.y, this.state.point2.x - this.state.point1.x) * 180 / Math.PI)-135}
            origin={`${this.state.point2.x}, ${this.state.point2.y}`}
        >
        <Path d={`M ${this.state.point2.x+8} ${this.state.point2.y+8} L ${this.state.point2.x-10} ${this.state.point2.y+10} L ${this.state.point2.x-8} ${this.state.point2.y-8} z`} fill="#1abc9c" stroke="#1abc9c" />
    </G>

    <Line
        x1={this.state.point1.x}
        y1={this.state.point1.y}
        x2={this.state.point2.x}
        y2={this.state.point2.y}
        stroke="#1abc9c"
        strokeWidth="10"
    />
</Svg>
```